# Javascript .getHours() not working properly

Tags: javascript

Why am I not getting a zero, but an "18", from `.getHours()`, when comparing two dates that are separated by only seconds?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="test">starting...</span>
    <script>
        var a = document.getElementById("test");

        window.setInterval(myHourCheck, 1000);

        var originalDate = new Date();

        function myHourCheck() {
            var current = new Date();
            var original = originalDate;
            var timeDelta = current.getTime() - original.getTime();

            var hours = new Date(timeDelta).getHours();

            a.innerHTML = hours;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Stepping through confirms that only seconds separate `current` from `original`.

Comment: `GetTime()` - `GetTime()` will return you the timestamp difference, so for `2016/06/09 20:00:01 - 2016/06/09 20:00:00` will return the timestamp 1 which is the `1970/01/01 00:00:01`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Date` constructs a Date object with your local time zone. The hour offset is screwing you up.

You can get around this by using the UTC versions of the methods:

```
new Date(0).getUTCHours() === 0
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Will accept once stack overflow timer allows me.